# Slide in and slide out animation on a view alternately displaces the view from its original position

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view

I have a view and two buttons which are used to slide up the view to the screen and the other button to slide it down. But if I keep pressing the buttons alternately the view does not return to its original position but is displaced.Here is the code

```
//button 1
Interpolator interpolator=new OvershootInterpolator();
        loginOptionsSheet.animate().translationYBy(-loginOptionsSheet.getHeight()).setDuration(550).setInterpolator(interpolator)
                .start();

//button 2
Interpolator interpolator=new FastOutLinearInInterpolator();
        loginOptionsSheet.animate().translationYBy(683).setDuration(300).setInterpolator(interpolator)
                .start();
```

Comment: Have you tried using the same hardcoded value for the translation? (i.e. use -683 for button 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you keep pressing the buttons, you are starting the animation over again in the middle of animating, and since you are using translationYBy the "origin" keeps moving as the animation restarts.
From the documentation

> The amount to be animated by, as an offset from the current value

So use translationY instead

> The value to be animated to

Note that you will have to change your values around as you will now be translating to the absolute position now instead of putting in the relative amount to change.